# Difference between bzero and setting char array equal to '\0'?

Tags: c++, buffer

I currently have a function:

```
void clearBuffer(char* buffer, int length)
{
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){ buffer[i] = '\0'; }
}
```

When I call this function with an array I get an error:

> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I call this function in the constructor of a class on a class variable that is defined public like:

```
#define MAXLEN 256
class Message
{
    public:
    Message();
    char msg[MAXLEN];
};
```

Implementation:

```
Message::Message()
{ 
    clearBuffer(msg, MAXLEN); 
}
```

Just for giggles, I changed the function to use `bzero`:

```
void clearBuffer(char* buffer, int length)
{
    bzero(buffer, length);
}
```

and now the function works and I am not getting the `Illegal instruction` error.

Are these two functions not equivalent? What could be causing the error in the first place?

**Note:** I only have this problem when I run the code on one of my virtual machines. When I run this on a the real production machine, no `Illegal instruction` appears.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: The main difference between `bzero()` and your original `clearBuffer()` is that `bzero()` is probably a lot faster. If the above code crashes there is probably something else at work than the difference between these two functions: The description of the error sounds like you are overwriting the stack which you could, e.g., achieve by doing `char buffer[1]; new(buffer) Message();`.

Comment: Is `MAXLEN` really the same in all your translation units? Replace the call with `clearBuffer(msg, sizeof msg)`.

Comment: I would likely simply put `msg()` on the constructor initializer list and call it a day. This, however, stems of a larger problem, with either the `Message` object itself being instantiated on bogus memory or, as Kerrek pointed out, a conflicting `MAXLEN` across translation units. Probably need more code (specifically, the code further up the stack that is instigating the construction).

Comment: @Pavel Anossov I am using `g++-4.7`. Another oddity, I only have this problem on one of my virtual machines. When I run this on a the real production machine, no `Illegal instuction` comes up.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the `Message` - that is likely where the problem comes from.

Comment: @dinkelk: Possibly that your VM doesn't support SSE or AVX or some other "exotic" instructions that the compiler decided to use for `bzero`.

Comment: @Mats Petersson `bzero` seems to work. It's the `for` loop that is broken. Also the code to create Messasge is just: `Message msg;` as all the real work is done in the constructor.

Comment: @dinkelk: I meant that the reason you get illegal opcode is to do with the VM's support for some of the more exotic instructions, perhaps. It's not unusual that these sort of things are masked off on the VM side to avoid problems if you decide to move your VM from one machine to another (it's no fun at all to have your VM in the middle of SSE execution, and end up on a machine that doesn't have SSE instructions!)

Comment: Try compiling with -march=native.